# php having issue with including javascript and quotes?

Tags: php, escaping, quotes, double-quotes

Here is my code:

```
$buffer .= '<legend>'.$thisField.'</legend><input type="text" name="'.$thisField.'" id="'.$thisField.'"/> <a href="javascript:;" onClick="mcImageManager.browse({fields : 'url_abs'});">[Pick file]</a><br /><small>360px W x 240px H</small><br /><br />';
```

It is breaking **syntax error, unexpected T_STRING**

I have tried every type of combination of single quotes, double quotes and escaping ??

I am at a loss, What am I missing??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases it's advisable to resort to [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) strings, also for readability:

```
$buffer .= <<<END
  <legend>$thisField</legend>
  <input type="text" name="$thisField" id="$thisField"/>
  <a href="javascript:;" onClick="mcImageManager.browse({fields : 'url_abs'});">[Pick file]</a>
  <br /><small>360px W x 240px H</small><br /><br />
END;
```

This avoids having to escape any quotes. And you can just write $variables as-is within such a block.

Comment: To be honest, I think this is approaching the point where it's advisable to use genuine templates, but HEREDOC is a good suggestion nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Just escape your quotes inside the string with a backslash:

```
$buffer .= '<legend>'.$thisField.'</legend><input type="text" name="'.$thisField.'" id="'.$thisField.'"/> <a href="javascript:;" onClick="mcImageManager.browse({fields : \'url_abs\'});">[Pick file]</a><br /><small>360px W x 240px H</small><br /><br />';
```

See [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\).

Answer (score 1):

As the highlighter tells you, php will fail near `{fields : 'url_abs'}`. You're inside a single quoted string, so you'll have to escape the single quotes inside the string:
`{fields : \'url_abs\'}`,

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the single quotes around url_abs.